# MySQL is not setting the DEFAULT value when a NULL is sent

Tags: php, mysql

[image: form image]

I have the following form on my website where it adds a supplier to the database.
The database suppliers table has

```
id(AI),
name(varchar),
company(varchar),
phone(int),
avatar(varchar)
```

Nothing is allowed to be null, the avatar column is a path to an image that the admin uploads, I have a DEFAULT path to an image called "def.jpg", now if I upload an image it inserts to the database successfully, but whenever I send it null, MySQL does not use the DEFAULT path set and hence why it also fails to insert the record at all, it is 100% correct path.

```php
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$uploadError = '';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    include 'db.php';
    $sName = $_POST['sName'];
    $company = $_POST['sCmp'];
    $phone = $_POST['sNumber'];
    $type = isset($_FILES['sPhoto']) ? (explode('.', $_FILES['sPhoto']['name'])) : null;
    if (!empty($type)) { //a file was upload
        $type = end($type); //get the extension
        $allowed = ['png', 'jpg'];
        if (in_array($type, $allowed)) { //type is allowed
            $tmp_name = $_FILES['sPhoto']['tmp_name'];
            $name = $_FILES['sPhoto']['name'];
            $target_dir = 'assets/images/suppliers/';

            //move the file to the target location
            $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["sPhoto"]["name"]);
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_file);

        } else { //not allowed so we set error message
            $uploadError = 'This type isnt allowed!';
            echo($uploadError);
        }

    } else { //no file was passed in so we let it continue to insert
        $target_file = null;
    }

    if (empty($uploadError)) { //no errors, so we insert
        $sql = "INSERT INTO suppliers (name,company,phone,avatar) VALUES (?,?,?,COALESCE(?, avatar, DEFAULT(avatar)));";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssis", $sName, $company, $phone, $target_file);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }

} else {
    if (isset($_POST['delSubmit'])) {
        include 'db.php';

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM suppliers WHERE name = ?;";
        $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $name);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    }
}
?>
    <!-- ***** Preloader Start ***** -->
    <div id="preloader">
        <div class="jumper">
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- ***** Preloader End ***** -->
    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="">
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['email'] === 'admin@allday.com') {
        include 'navadmin.php';
    } else {
        include 'navuser.php';
    }
} else {
    include 'nav.php';
}

?>
```

After I've read some comments below, I've checked that whenever I do not upload an image , it goes into " this type is not allowed " block, instead of using MySQL's DEFAULT value.
[image: Table Structure Picture]

Comment: I'm confused. You start about asking about PHP MyAdmin and then switch to some custom PHP code that you wrote. Which isn't behaving the way you expect? PHP MyAdmin or your code?

Comment: fyi, `shell.png.php` would bypass your validation

Comment: I am not sure why PhPMyAdmin is not setting the default value when I send a NULL, I provided all of the information I could because I couldn't locate it myself.

Comment: phpMyAdmin doesn't do anything related to your PHP code. It's just a tool (one of several available) for managing a mySQL database. Maybe you're really trying to say that mysql isn't doing what you expected.

Comment: Alright I will edit the question to make life easier

Comment: Provide your PHP code as well. Don't fill the `avatar` column in your code and it should work.

Comment: I was just told that its not related to my code above hehe, but no worries I will add it again

Comment: I think I deleted someone's comment by accident, dayum.

Comment: I removed phpMyAdmin as this question doesn't look related to phpMyAdmin in any way.

Comment: NULL is a value. So when you provide NULL, then the default is not used. However, your column does not allow NULL values, so it results in error. Simple as that.

Comment: phpmyadmin is not your database, it is just a client you may be using to access your database.  please show the output of `select version();` so we can see what version your database is?

Answer (score 1):

Your question has:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (name,company,phone,avatar) VALUES (?,?,?,COALESCE(?, avatar, DEFAULT(avatar)));
```

There's an extra "avatar" there that doesn't belong; presumably you mean:

```
INSERT INTO suppliers (name,company,phone,avatar) VALUES (?,?,?,COALESCE(?, DEFAULT(avatar)));
```

Comment: Good morning, thanks for your reply but I did not solve the problem, still goes into " Type not allowed " whenever I send the avatar null in the form.

Comment: Do some debugging; is `isset($_FILES['sPhoto'])` true?  If not, why not? If so, what are `$_FILES['sPhoto']['name']` and `explode('.', $_FILES['sPhoto']['name'])`?